# Build data.tar.gz instead of data.tar.xz inside deb

Tags: dpkg

I just updated to dpkg 1.17 and it now defaults to compressing data.tar with xz instead of gzip. That creates a problem when I'm remastering CD's for older versions of ubuntu.

Is there a way to tell dpkg-buildpackage to create data.tar.gz instead of xz? I tried `-Zgzip` without success.

---

Related manpages:

[dpkg-buildpackage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dpkg-buildpackage.1.html)

> **-z, -Z**
>
> Passed unchanged to dpkg-source. See its manual page.

[dpkg-source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dpkg-source.1.html)

> **-Zcompression, --compression=compression**
>
> Specify the compression to use for created files (tarballs and diffs).
>   Note that this option will not cause existing tarballs to be
>   recompressed, it only affects new files. Supported values are: gzip,
>   bzip2, lzma and xz.  gzip is the default. xz is only supported since
>   dpkg-dev 1.15.5.

Comment: Although an old question I believe that the answer from @c0ff3m4kr is correct and should be marked as  such? I also suggest that the "Related manpages" in this questions should be removed as they are misleading to the OP's question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem while using newly build packages on an older server (hardy) which I couldn't update. The `dpkg-source` isn't responsible for creating a .deb package. It is only used to create the source package.

In fact `dpkg-deb` creates the packages witch is normally called by `dh_builddeb` in `debian/rules`. You can add change this command to `dh_builddeb -- -Zgzip` or call `dpkg-deb -Zgzip` directly.

If the command `dh_builddeb` isn't listed explicitly in the `debian/rules` file
you can add the following lines to make it work:

```
override_dh_builddeb:
        dh_builddeb -- -Zgzip
```

Note that before the `dh_builddeb` option there is only one tab, not multiple spaces as this is a [Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131213/can-you-make-valid-makefiles-without-tab-characters).

Comment: Makes sense, though I was unable to test it

Comment: @Penz I just tested that giving -Z gzip to dpkg-buildpackage does not work - as this answer explains - and that using dh_builddeb in the rules file do in fact work.

Comment: This no longer works on Linux kernel 5.x builds - the debian/rules file is overwritten when running `make deb-pkg`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it doesn't work for you, but in Debian it works as intended:

```
$ dpkg-buildpackage -Zgzip 
dpkg-buildpackage: source package lastfm
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1:1.5.4.27091+dfsg1-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by John Stamp <jstamp@users.sourceforge.net>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture i386
 dpkg-source -Zgzip --before-build lastfm-1.5.4.27091+dfsg1
dpkg-source: warning: unknown information field 'Dm-Upload-Allowed' in input data in general section of control info file
```

If I try to use anything else:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -Zgz  
dpkg-buildpackage: source package lastfm
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1:1.5.4.27091+dfsg1-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by John Stamp <jstamp@users.sourceforge.net>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture i386
 dpkg-source -Zgz --before-build lastfm-1.5.4.27091+dfsg1
dpkg-source: gz is not a supported compression

Use --help for program usage information.
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -Zgz --before-build lastfm-1.5.4.27091+dfsg1 gave error exit status 2
```

It err. You must make sure that you have gzip installed.

Comment: I do have gzip installed, and dpkg-buildpackage passes it to dpkg-source, but I still get data.tar.xz.

Comment: Could you tell me which package?

Comment: ubuntu-keyring. Right now I'm using a script that extracts data.tar.xz, recompresses it with gzip and puts it back in deb.