# How can I use equivs-build to build packages that can be installed on older versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, 10.04, dpkg, deb

I have several versions of Ubuntu installed, including 14.04 and 10.04. When I build packages using [equivs-build](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/equivs) on 14.04, it generates `.deb`s that contain `.xz`-compressed data. The version of `dpkg` on 10.04 cannot understand or install these packages, and so I see errors like this:

> dpkg-deb: file `/var/cache/apt/archives/mypackage.deb' contains
>   ununderstood data member data.tar.xz

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396088/build-data-tar-gz-instead-of-data-tar-xz-inside-deb) gives an approach for building Debian packages in general, but it doesn't appear equivs-build gives that level of control; unless I've missed an obvious option?

Comment: Did you try the options proposed in this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/396088/build-data-tar-gz-instead-of-data-tar-xz-inside-deb ? using `dpkg-buildpackage -Zgz` could help you getting a deb file to use with 10.04.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add a link to that answer, I had seen it, yes. It doesn't help in my case because I'm using equivs; I don't have a complete Debian package structure so can't run the 'standard' Debian packaging tools.

Answer (score 0):

- You may try setting environment variable from `debuild`

  ```
  DEBUILD_DPKG_BUILDPACKAGE_OPTS=Zzgip
  ```
- If `equivs` doesn't use `debuild` when building only binary package (default). Go with full build, as its manpage stated

  ```
  equivs-build -f ..
  ```

Answer (score -1):

I am building bebian too and I found out how to manage the equivs-contol / -build.

how to include the BINARIES:

- I st -->  copy all the files in the working directory as they are. Example myPackage-meta.
- 2 nd --> open the configuration file generate with equivs-control and modify the option "Files:", remove the hash and be careful of the **indentation**.

  Example:

`Files: binary-qt /usr/local/bin/
 second-binary-daemon /usr/local/bin/`

before "second-binary-daemon" you need a space only and use this indentation for the further files.

And so on.

- 3 rd --> save the config file and execute equivs-build

Done!

for the configuration file and the rough instructions, you need to discover the details, I give you the manual link:
[Sintax of the equivs-build](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/equivs/equivs-build.1.en.html)

Hope will be useful! Brake a leg!

PS: You need to compile the binary first.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think that's relevant to my question. I'm trying to understand how I can backport my packages to older versions of Ubuntu because of the differences in package compression.

Comment: Should be run the distribution in a virtual machine and use equivs on it. I remind Ubuntu 10.04 is very light.
Keep in mind Ubuntu had done a lot of improvements and the versions sometimes are very different.